# uploading files to a folder is not Working

Tags: php

I have a problem with my code. The function MOVE_UPLOADED_FILE is not adding the file to the destiny folder. It inserts the name to the database correctly but the folder still empty. I'm not experienced on uploading files so... I hope you can help me.

```
<?php
// configuration
include('../connect.php');

// new data
$id = $_POST['memi'];
$a = $_POST['code'];
$z = $_POST['gen'];
$b = $_POST['name'];
$c = $_POST['exdate'];
$d = $_POST['price'];
$e = $_POST['kategori'];
$f = $_POST['qty'];
$g = $_POST['o_price'];
$h = $_POST['profit'];
$i = $_POST['date_arrival'];
$j = $_POST['sold'];
$nama_file = $_POST['namaFile'];

    if (! empty($_FILES['namaFile']['tmp_name'])) {
    $nama_file = $_FILES['namaFile']['name'];
    $nama_file = stripslashes($nama_file);
    $nama_file = str_replace("'","",$nama_file);
    $nama_file = str_replace(" ","-",$nama_file);
    $nama_file = $a.".".$nama_file;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['namaFile']['tmp_name'], "images/".$nama_file);
}
else {

    echo "error";
}
// query
$sql = "UPDATE products 
    SET product_code=?, gen_name=?, product_name=?, expiry_date=?, price=?,kd_kategori=?, qty=?, o_price=?, profit=?, date_arrival=?, qty_sold=?,file_gambar=?
WHERE product_id=?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($a,$z,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$nama_file,$id));
header("location: products.php");

?>
```

Comment: Can you try add `@ `to `move_uploaded_ file` like `@move_uploaded_file` ?

Comment: I am going to assume this is non-production code and suggest a much more robust function that validates the file extension, size, etc. Upon first glance, I would imagine your issue is with the path or permissions of the folder you are trying to store the file. You may need to use `chmod` to set the correct permissions first. Also, you will probably want to use `isset` instead of `empty` because if the index (['tmp_name']) doesn't exist you will likely get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the enctype attribute to your HTML Form tag:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Server side handling file upload:

```
<?php 
//some code here 
if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {
    $tmpfname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    //make some security checks here
    if(!@move_uploaded_file($tmpfname, 'images/'.$filename)){
        echo 'error';
    } //else file uploaded successfuly
} else { 
    echo 'Upload failed or no file selected';
}
?>
```

Optional: if you are on a Unix or Linux-based OS, the 'images' directory must be writable (chmod 777 ./images)